# Transfering Files to a folder by name in Rstudio

Tags: r, file

I'm working with several images ".tif" classified by year (2017,2019). and I want to split the images into 2 different folders for the mentioned years in Rstudio.

My data is organized as follows:

```
ruta_bandas
[1] "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/arvi_2017_june.tif" 
[2] "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/arvi_2019_june.tif" 
[3] "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/arvi_yc.tif"        
[4] "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/avi_2017_june.tif"  
[5] "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/avi_2019_june.tif"  
[6] "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/avi_yc.tif"  
.
.
```

The "arvi_yc" for the process aren't relevant

They are all in the same folder, and as you can see, the files have the year (2017/2019) expressed in the name of the image.

I was wondering if is possible to classify in folders/year the images that I have in a loop that drags automatically each file to its destination folder.

I managed to create the Folders in R ,

```
head(folder)
[1] "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/"
    
for (i in 1:length(folder)){
        
        outputdir <- paste0(folder[i],"Landsat2019/")
        
        # Create output folder
        if (!dir.exists(outputdir)){
          dir.create(outputdir)
        } else {
          print("Dir already exists!")
        }
      }
    for (i in 1:length(folder)){
        
        outputdir <- paste0(folder[i],"Landsat2017/")
        
        # Create output folder
        if (!dir.exists(outputdir)){
          dir.create(outputdir)
        } else {
          print("Dir already exists!")
        }
      }
```

would be nice to know your comments,

thanks

Comment: Some files do not have a year, `"arvi_yc.tif"`. What to do with them, leave them be?

Comment: Can you post `head(folder)` in the question, please?

Comment: I put the head (folder) ;)

Comment: The "arvi_yc" for the process aren't relevant

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Untested since I don't have those files.

```
folder <-
c("./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/arvi_2017_june.tif", 
  "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/arvi_2019_june.tif", 
  "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/arvi_yc.tif", 
  "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/avi_2017_june.tif", 
  "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/avi_2019_june.tif", 
  "./LIDAR/ALSPlots/sentinel/6_mosaic/avi_yc.tif")

years <- gsub("^.*_([[:digit:]]+)_.*$|^.*_(yc).*$", "\\1\\2", folder)
years <- sort(years)
path <- unique(dirname(folder))

mapply(function(x, y, path){
  newdir <- file.path(path, paste0("Landstat", y))
  newfile <- file.path(newdir, basename(x))
  if(!dir.exists(newdir)) dir.create(newdir)
  file.rename(x, newfile)
}, split(folder, years), unique(years), MoreArgs = list(path = path))
```